Plot array of integers as horizontal lines on chart tradingview pinescript
I am trying to Plot array of integers as horizontal lines on chart tradingview pinescript, the array will have around 2000 numbers. I want to plot numbers that haven't touched price today (9:15 am to 3:30 pm) and are 0.5% close to current price.Any guidance/snippet is appreciated
//@version=5
indicator("Price Pattern Highlighter", overlay=true)

// Define the array of specific prices to highlight
var float[] pricePatterns = array.from(44044, 43743, 43843, 44444, 44555, 43777, 42888, 43521, 48500)
var line[] lines = array.new_line()  // Array to hold line objects

// Function to check if the current price is within 0.5% of any price pattern and draw lines
checkAndDrawPatterns(price) =>
    tolerance = 0.005 // 0.5% tolerance
    for i = 0 to array.size(pricePatterns) - 1
        pattern = array.get(pricePatterns, i)
        // Check if price is within the tolerance range
        if price >= pattern * (1 - tolerance) and price <= pattern * (1 + tolerance)
            // Check if we've already drawn a line for this pattern
            if array.size(lines) <= i or array.get(lines, i) == na
                // Draw a new line if none exists
                l = line.new(bar_index, pattern, bar_index + 1, pattern, width=2, color=color.red, extend=extend.both)
                array.set(lines, i, l)
            else
                // Update the line position to the current pattern price if it already exists
                line.set_xy1(array.get(lines, i), bar_index, pattern)
                line.set_xy2(array.get(lines, i), bar_index + 1, pattern)
        else
            // If price is out of the tolerance range, delete the line if it exists
            if array.size(lines) > i and array.get(lines, i) != na
                line.delete(array.get(lines, i))
                array.set(lines, i, na)

// Check patterns on each bar update
checkAndDrawPatterns(close)

